# Libcurl C++: issues retrieving HTTP response code

Tags: c++, http, curl, libcurl, http-response-codes

**Goal:**

Using a slightly modified example of the `libcurl` program called "http2-download.c" [found at this link](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http2-download.html), I am trying to retrieve the `HTTP response code` for any responses returned to the application, and to then print the response codes to the terminal. Another similar question [can be found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136930/c-libcurl-http-response-code-issues)

**Expected result:**

To receive a `HTTP response code` of 200 for each returned request.

**Actual result:**

Receiving a `HTTP response code` of 0 for each.

**Information:**

Currently, for each of the three requests returned from the destination server, the `HTTP response code` returned is `0` despite the correct payload being displayed on the terminal containing the web page content. If I run the following `curl` command from the terminal, I also receive the correct payload and a code of 200.

```
curl -i -X GET https://httpstat.us/200
```

For a number of different `libcurl` programs, I have successfully retrieved the HTTP response code using the following:

```
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
```

**Code attempt:**

Used the above `getinfo` line of code to retrieve the `HTTP response code` in the below function called `setup(...)`, since I've used another line of code within the same function which successfully controls the callback function `write_data(...)` so thought this was an appropriate location. Furthermore, `curl_easy_init()` is also called in this function before the `getinfo` so I am not sure why I am receiving a 0 each time.

Code is compiled using `g++ test.cpp -lcurl -o test`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/mprintf.h>

#ifndef CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX
#define CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX 0
#endif

struct transfer {
        CURL *easy;
        unsigned int num;
        FILE *out;
};

#define NUM_HANDLES 1000

size_t write_data(void *buffer, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
        return size * nmemb;
}

static void setup(struct transfer *t, int num)
{
        CURL *hnd;
        hnd = t->easy = curl_easy_init();

        /* set the same URL */
        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://httpstat.us/200");


        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

        /* HTTP/2 please */
        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);

        /* we use a self-signed test server, skip verification during debugging */
        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

        long response_code;
        curl_easy_getinfo(hnd, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
        std::cout << "RESPONSE CODE: " << response_code << std::endl;

        #if (CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX > 0)
        /* wait for pipe connection to confirm */
        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_PIPEWAIT, 1L);
        #endif
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        struct transfer trans[NUM_HANDLES];
        CURLM *multi_handle;
        int i;
        int still_running = 0; /* keep number of running handles */
        int num_transfers;

        if(argc > 1) {
        /* if given a number, do that many transfers */
        num_transfers = atoi(argv[1]);
        if((num_transfers < 1) || (num_transfers > NUM_HANDLES))
                num_transfers = 3; /* a suitable low default */
        }
        else
                num_transfers = 3; /* suitable default */

        /* init a multi stack */
        multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
        for(i = 0; i < num_transfers; i++) {
                setup(&trans[i], i);

                /* add the individual transfer */
                curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, trans[i].easy);
        }
        curl_multi_setopt(multi_handle, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX);

        do {
                CURLMcode mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);

                if(still_running)
                        /* wait for activity, timeout or "nothing" */
                        mc = curl_multi_poll(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL);

                if(mc)
                        break;
        } while(still_running);

        for(i = 0; i < num_transfers; i++) {
                curl_multi_remove_handle(multi_handle, trans[i].easy);
                curl_easy_cleanup(trans[i].easy);
        }

        curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle);

        return 0;
}
```

**Summary / Question:**

The URL is working correctly, returning the correct payload and a HTTP response code of 200 when using other methods like calling curl from the terminal. Can anyone please troubleshoot and modify this code so that the `HTTP response code` is returned from each request and prints `200`?

Comment: You get the response code in the `setup` function, before you do any request. You need to do it once you have made a successful request.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried the following line of code after `curl_multi_perform(...)` is called within the `do-while` loop using the multi-handle `mc` but receive the error `error: cannot convert ‘CURLMcode’ to ‘CURL*’ {aka ‘void*’}`. The line of code: `curl_easy_getinfo(mc, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);` If you have any ideas I'd really appreciate any info

Comment: Why are you trying to pass `CURLMcode mc` as the first arg of `curl_easy_getinfo`?